# R-markdown Data Display

Tags: r, dataframe, r-markdown

I am new to using r markdown. I am writing an explanation for a chapter of the class book.

The data frame is called "bank.df", it has 26874 observations and 21 variables.

When running the r markdown as a word document. It shows the whole data set which takes a lot of pages. Is there a way I can write inside of {r} to tell R how to show the first 100 observations and the last 100? Also, I tried to use a frame for the table but I was unsuccessful.

Here is my attempt:

````
---
title: "Ch3_Note_Class"
author: "Name"
date: '2022-11-04'
output: word_document
---

```{r}
library(rmarkdown)
library(knitr)
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
```
#Import file 

```{r, results='asis'}
bank.df = read.csv("file location")

library(knitr)
View(bank_train)
str(bank_train)
dim(bank_train)
knitr::kable(bank.df[1:5,1:5], format="word_document")

```
````

Comment: Unless I am explicitly troubleshooting `knitr` or other things about the code, I would never have `View` or `str` in a production rmarkdown document. `View`, for one, is intended to be used interactively, so its use here does not seem correct.

Comment: To address your question, *"first 100 ... last 100"* should be straight-forward using `[`-indexing as you're already doing, or by combining `head(bank.df,100)` and `tail(bank.df,100)`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but for some reason, it prints to me only one column with the vertical line.

Comment: ```{r, results='asis'}
bank_train = read.csv("file location")
library(knitr)
dim(bank_train)
knitr::kable(bank_train[1:100,1:21], format="html")

```